# v8: Allocation failed - process out of memory in Titanium Android

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

I have been using Titanium to develop an application for android.Last night i saw an unexpected behaviour. Every time i launch application,it just hangs for sometime and crashes after sometime.I checked the logs and its like below.Any help?

```
[ERROR] : v8: [ERROR] : v8: #
[ERROR] : v8: # Fatal error in JS
[ERROR] : v8: #
[ERROR] : v8: Allocation failed - process out of memory
[ERROR] : v8: [ERROR] : v8: #
[ERROR] : v8:
```

Comment: i've seen out of memory issues fixed by restarting the emulator, the whole machine and/or freeing up hard disk space. Not sure if that'll help you or not.

Comment: i see this when i run on device @phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question so that it would help someone else.
I had a loop in homepage which accidentally caused to be run infinite.which turns to cause the out of memory at end.